# Not able to see mails in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird

I recently migrated my Thunderbird data from one Windows 7 PC to another Windows 7 PC. After migration when I open Thunderbird, I can see three heading in main page - Email, Accounts and Advanced Features. Inside Email there are two links - Read messages and Write a new message. Nothing happens when I click on Read messages even though Write a new message is working. So I'm unable to read my mails. Please help.

Comment: Verify that the POP3 settings are correct for each email account.  If you still have the old computer, just compare the settings to verify that they match.

Comment: How did you migrate TB?